# Any way to generate bubblechart with loglog scale

Tags: plotting, charts

I would like to draw a bubblechart with loglog scale

I have a data set such as:

```
review = {{1500000000, 0.066666667, 0.001333, 0.05, 0.001333333, 0.1, 
0.075, "CEBAF Opr"}, {1500000000, 2.666666667, 0.05333, 0.05, 
0.053333333, 4, 0.075, "CEBAF R&D"}, {120, 12000, 6, 2, 6, 
0.00144, 0.00000024, "SLC"}, {10000, 7500, 4.688, 2, 3.75, 0.0375,
 0.00001, "EIC R&D"}, {8, 7500, 1.6, 4.375, 4.6875, 0.00006, 
1.28 10^-8, "EIC Specs"}, {2500000, 0.02, 0.0000125, 1.6, 
0.0000125, 0.00005, 0.004, "MAMI"}, {10, 250000, 0.01, 25000, 
0.01, 0.0025, 0.00025, "MIT-BATES"}, {50, 100000, 0.1, 1000, 0.1, 
0.005, 0.00005, "Bonn-ELSA"}};
```

The first element is x, the second element is y and bubble size is the third element,
I tried

```
    BubbleChart[
 Table[{review[[n, 1]], review[[n, 2]], review[[n, 3]]}, {n, 
   Length[review]}], Frame -> True, 
 FrameLabel -> {"Frequency[Hz]", "Bunch Charge [pC]"}]
```

[image: I cannot find log in the bubblechart, all the bubbles are overlapped]

Any suggestions to make a better bubblechart in Mathematica?

Appreciate @kglr's answer, I put Scalingfunctions on, however the ChartLabels does not work...

```
    Show[Plot[{10^13/fre, 10^11/fre, 10^9/fre, 10^7/fre, 10^5/fre, 10^3/
   fre, 10/fre, 0.1/fre}, {fre, 1, 10^10}, GridLines -> Automatic, 
  PlotStyle -> {{Gray, Dashed, Thick}}, Frame -> True, 
  FrameLabel -> {"Frequency [Hz]", "Bunch Charge [pC]"}, 
  ScalingFunctions -> {"Log", "Log"}, 
  PlotRange -> {{1, 10^10}, {0.01, 10^6}}, PlotTheme -> "Scientific", 
  AspectRatio -> 0.9], 
 BubbleChart[review[[All, ;; 3]], 
  GridLinesStyle -> Directive[Gray, Dashed], 
  ChartLabels -> Placed[review[[All, 8]], Center], 
  LabelingSize -> Full, ChartStyle -> 45, 
  ScalingFunctions -> {"Log", "Log"}, BubbleSizes -> {0.04, 0.17}]
 ]
```

[image]

Comment: Evaluate `Options[BubbleChart]`

Answer (score 5):

**Update:** When we use `ScalingFunctions -> {"Log","Log"}` with the option `ChartLabels -> ...` the labels do not show:

```
labels = CharacterRange["A", "Z"][[;; Length@review]];

BubbleChart[review[[All, ;; 3]], Frame -> True, 
 FrameLabel -> {"Frequency[Hz]", "Bunch Charge [pC]"}, 
 ChartLabels -> labels]
```

[image]

```
BubbleChart[review[[All, ;; 3]], Frame -> True, 
 FrameLabel -> {"Frequency[Hz]", "Bunch Charge [pC]"}, 
 ScalingFunctions -> {"Log", "Log"}, ChartLabels -> labels]
```

[image]

***A work-around:*** Define an association linking `labels` to the `Log` of xy coordinates:

```
labelsToXY = AssociationThread[labels, Log @ review[[All, ;; 2]]];
```

We can use `labelsToXY` in several ways:

1. Add the labels using `Epilog`:

```
BubbleChart[review[[All, ;; 3]], Frame -> True, 
 FrameLabel -> {"Frequency[Hz]", "Bunch Charge [pC]"}, 
 ScalingFunctions -> {"Log", "Log"}, 
 Epilog -> (Text[#, labelsToXY @ #] & /@ labels)]
```

[image]

2. Post-process `BubbleChart` output to correct the positions of labels:

```
ReplaceAll[Text[t_, a_, b___] :> Text[t, labelsToXY @ t[[1]], b]] @
 BubbleChart[review[[All, ;; 3]], Frame -> True, 
  FrameLabel -> {"Frequency[Hz]", "Bunch Charge [pC]"}, 
  ScalingFunctions -> {"Log", "Log"}, ChartLabels -> labels]
```

> same picture

3. Use the option `DisplayFunction` to do the post-processing inside `BubbleChart`:

```
BubbleChart[review[[All, ;; 3]], Frame -> True, 
 FrameLabel -> {"Frequency[Hz]", "Bunch Charge [pC]"}, 
 ScalingFunctions -> {"Log", "Log"}, ChartLabels -> labels, 
 DisplayFunction -> 
   ReplaceAll[Text[t_, a_, b___] :> Text[t, labelsToXY @ t[[1]], b]]]
```

> same picture

**Original answer:**

Add the option `ScalingFunctions -> {"Log", "Log"}`:

```
BubbleChart[review[[All, ;;3]],
 Frame -> True, 
 FrameLabel -> {"Frequency[Hz]", "Bunch Charge [pC]"}, 
 ScalingFunctions -> {"Log", "Log"}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much.

Comment: Looks once add Scalingfunctions on, the ChartLabels does not work... Any ideas?

Comment: @rfeynman, it looks like a bug. Please add your comment to your post so that  it is more visible. I will post a work-around to get the labels right.

Comment: ,Thank you, I updated the question.